# Using Bootstrap's grid, is there a way to vertically align without creating a new row?

Tags: css, grid, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

Suppose I have the following HTML (well, haml, but...):

```
.container
  .row
    .span4
      %h1
      %p
      %img
    .span4
      %h1
      %p
      %img
    .span4
      %h1
      %p
      %img
```

So, each column has a header, some text, and an image. Is there a way to get the images to align vertically as if they were done like this:

```
.container
  .row
    .span4
      %h1
      %p
    .span4
      %h1
      %p
    .span4
      %h1
      %p
  .row
    .span4
      %img
    .span4
      %img
    .span4
      %img
```

but without creating a new row? The reason is, I'd like the images to be grouped with the headers and text, so that on mobile/tablet layouts, the images are laid out with the content they match with, whereas in the second case, you'll get three groups of text and then three images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of 2 approaches :

In any case, the `img-outer` may not be necessary in certain cases.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <h1></h1>
            <p></p>
            <div class="img-outer"><img src="" /></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Height *control*

If you **set a fixed height for the text elements** `h1` and `p` above, then your images will be aligned.

You can also **set a fixed height for the `.span`** and use absolute positioning. This one is shown below :

```css
.container .row [class*="span"] {
    height: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.container .row [class*="span"] .img-outer{
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    /* Take the whole width */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/K3PkD/)

#### Other positionning

Seems to work, I don't have enough absolute positionning knowledge to guarantee that the results are cross-browser.

```css
.container .row {
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.container .row [class*="span"] .img-outer{
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    /* Take the whole width */
    width: 300px; /* .span4 width */
}
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/K3PkD/3/)